# Why is 'malloced_memory' lower than 'used_heap_size' in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, malloc, heap-memory, v8

In [every example](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8_v8_getheapstatistics) of `v8.getHeapStatistics()` the `malloced_memory` seems to be lower than `used_heap_size`:

```json
{
  total_heap_size: 7326976,
  total_heap_size_executable: 4194304,
  total_physical_size: 7326976,
  total_available_size: 1152656,
  used_heap_size: 3476208,
  heap_size_limit: 1535115264,
  malloced_memory: 16384,
  peak_malloced_memory: 1127496,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 1,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

How can `malloced_memory` be lower than `used_heap_size`? Isn't `used_heap_size` a subset of `malloced_memory`?

My assumptions (obviously incorrect, unless `malloced_memory` is in KB and `used_heap_size` is in B):

- `malloced_memory`: total memory acquired from the OS (needed to create the V8 heap, store `Buffer`s, etc.).
- `used_heap_size`: the total size of all objects on the V8 heap (including uncollected garbage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

Memory for the managed heap is `mmap`ed, not `malloc`ed, so it's not expected to be a subset.